# In the react docs why is binding of *this* preferred over arrow functions for event handlers?

Tags: javascript, patterns-and-practices, reactjs

In the React docs, the constructor functions of class components contain lines where `this` is explicitly bound for event handlers e.g. [in the docs for handling events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
  }

  ...
}
```

When using arrow functions the binding is no longer required i.e

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
  }
  ...
}
```

Is there a good reason for preferring the explicit binding over the arrow functions?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using `bind(this)` and/or arrow functions directly in the `render` function there are no performance differences and the reasons why it's present in the documentation is most likely purely historical.

Choose one style and adhere to it. Stay consistent, do not mix both of them and you will be fine.